# Adding Logic To Check If Infra is In Account and Deploying If Not AWS-CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

The title may be a big vague so let me clarify. I am currently trying to enable AWSConfig rules and in order to do this the account must have AWSConfigurationRecorder and AWSDeliveryChannel. The issue lies that when an account already has this enabled, it will error out your entire stack when trying to deploy. I am trying to figure out a way to create logic that would essentially check if the AWSConfigurationRecorder or AWSDeliveryChannel are already there and if they are to skip over it and deploy just the rules and visa versa. Here is the code:

```
export class fullConfigStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);
      const globalConfigRole = new iam.Role(this, 'globalConfigRole', {
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('config.amazonaws.com'),   // required
    });
    globalConfigRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSConfigRoleForOrganizations'));
    globalConfigRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('ReadOnlyAccess'));
    
      const globalConfigRecorder = new config.CfnConfigurationRecorder(this, 'globalConfigRecorder',{
        roleArn: globalConfigRole.roleArn,    
        name: 'globalConfigRecorder',
        recordingGroup: {
          allSupported: true,
          includeGlobalResourceTypes: true
      }
    });
    const globalConfigBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'globalConfigBucket',{
        accessControl: s3.BucketAccessControl.LOG_DELIVERY_WRITE
      });
    const cisConfigDeliveryChannel = new config.CfnDeliveryChannel(this,'cisConfigDeliveryChannel',{
        s3BucketName: globalConfigBucket.bucketName,
        configSnapshotDeliveryProperties: {
            deliveryFrequency: 'TwentyFour_Hours'
        }
    });
    const generalConfigRole = new iam.Role(this,  'generalConfigRole',{
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('config.amazonaws.com')
      });

      const cloudTrailEnabledRule = new ManagedRule(this, 'cloudTrailEnabledRule', {
        identifier: 'CLOUD_TRAIL_ENABLED'
      });
```

So to clarify again I want to add some if/else logic with the cisConfigDeliveryChannel and globalConfigRecorder as to not error out the entire stack! If there is another way to solve this that I'm not seeing, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AWS CloudFormation template, you can [create a Lambda-backed custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) with a function that checks whether your resources exist or not. This Lambda function then returns an identifier for CloudFormation to determine if the resources need to be created.

Comment: hmm let me see if I can find some documentation for this with aws-cdk. Thank you.

Comment: Here’s the AWS documentation for the CDK custom-resources module: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html

Comment: thank you very much, allow me to look it over and I will report back on an answer!

Comment: Cool, happy to help!